Why the prediction results are shifted one day ahead in TensorFlow Conv2D Model?
enter image description hereI trained a Conv2D model using the TensorFlow library in Python to forecast daily water levels (t+1) in a region. The input data consisted of two raster images of rainfall and discharge for the day (t), while the output is the forecasted water level on day (t+1). After training the model, I tested it and found that the prediction results are shifted one day ahead of the actual values, as shown in the figure. What could be wrong? I suspect there might be an issue with the TensorFlow library because I have seen other people complaining about the same problem, as shown in the shared link:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21755
I tried to train the model with different data structures but the problem still persists.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
